# issue with getting JSON child values by specifying full path

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, underscore.js

I have the below JSON response

```
{
    "r": [{
            "IsDefault": false,
            "re": {
                    "Name": "Depo"            
                  },
            "Valid": "Oct8, 2013",
            "Clg":[ {
                      "Name": "james",
                      "Rate": 0.05
                    },   
                    {
                      "Name": "Jack",
                      "Rate": 0.55
                    }, 
                    {
                      "Name": "Mcd",
                      "Rate": 0.01,
                    }],
        },
      {
          "IsDefault": false,
          "re": {
                  "Name": "Depo"
                },
         "Valid": "Oct8, 2013",
         "Clg": [{
                   "Name": "james",
                   "Rate": 0.05
                 }, 
                 {
                   "Name": "Jack",
                   "Rate": 0.55
                 }, 
                 {
                   "Name": "Mcd",
                   "Rate": 0.01,
                 }],
      },
    {
        "IsDefault": false,
        "re": {
                "Name": "Depo"
              },
        "Valid": "Oct8, 2013",
        "Clg": [{
                  "Name": "james",
                  "Rate": 0.05
                }, 
                {
                  "Name": "Jack",
                  "Rate": 0.55
                }, 
                {
                  "Name": "Mcd",
                  "Rate": 0.01,
                }],
     }]
}
```

I am using $.getJSON method to loads JSON data and adding it in collection by checking whether it is array as below . It is working fine as expected.

```
var res = loadFromJson(result.r);
loadFromJson = function(input) {
    if (_.isArray(input)) {
    console.log("Inside Array");
      var collection = new CompeCollection();
      _.each(input, function(modData) {
        collection.add(loadFromJson(modData));
        console.log("collection length:"+modData.length);
      });
      return collection;
    }
  };
```

But when i try to specify the exact path(r.Clg) of my JSON response it is not even coming to above if condition though it is valid response.

```
 var res = loadFromJson(result.r.Clg);
loadFromJson = function(input) {
    if (_.isArray(input)) {
    console.log("Inside Array");
      var collection = new CompeCollection();
      _.each(input, function(modData) {
        collection.add(loadFromJson(modData));
        console.log("collection length:"+modData.length);
      });
      return collection;
    }
  };
```

What should i do when i need to specify actual or full path?

Can any one tell me what could be the problem when i pass more specific json values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: r is an array, it should be r[0].Clg

Comment: Hi, correct, it was small mistake anyhow thanks Quad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result.r.Clg` doesn't exist. `result.r` is an array.

If you only wanted to access the first object in the `r` array, you would do this:

```
var res = loadFromJson(result.r);
var clg = res[0].Clg;
```

Or you could loop over all the objects, perhaps capturing all the Clgs in one array:

```
var clgs = res.map(function (obj) { return obj.Clg; }, []);
```

Comment: It was my mistake. Thanks for your quick response.